# Can I visualize the photo location of the photos in a Shared Albums in Apple Photos?

Tags: iphone, apple-aperture, apple, macbook

Can I visualize the photo location of the photos in a Shared Albums in Apple Photos or do I have to import them first?

Answer (score 0):

If location data was included for the published items (shared album) you should be able to see it... it's a preference option.

Answer (score 0):

Photos.iOS will show the Photo Location map for an album but NOT for a Shared Album. Photos.macOS will show Location data for a Library (does not support for album level) but I am pretty sure this doesn't include Shared Albums.

I would say the answer is No.